# Are there culinary uses for the water left from peeling almonds?

Tags: culinary-uses, peeling, water, almonds

Is there a possible use for the water used for peeling almonds?

*(Throw the almonds in boiling water and let them soak for a couple of mins before peeling them: the water left is yellowish and almond scented)*

Comment: I originally posted an answer but I actually completely misread your question... I was just saying that you can just leave the almonds in lukewarm water for 5-10 mins no need of boiling water.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, there is no reason not to use it. However, I'm hard pressed to think of a good place, generally because good cooking prefers other, stronger flavored liquids instead of water.

An application where you can have the flavor on its own would be making ayran or a lassi. I think it would be an improvement over plain-water-ayran.

For other uses, just substitute plain water to get a slight nutty hint. I like to pair rice with nuts, so you could use it instead of pure water to cook rice. Or add it to a pot of stock you are making - with a complex stock of a meat and several vegetables, it will be too subtle a taste to register consciously, but will enrich the flavor as a whole. For a simpler stock (e.g. just chicken with classic mirepoix) the taste of almonds can get too strong, depending on the quantity you use.

Answer (score 2):

You could use it when making horchata. It is a drink made with rice, cinnamon, sugar and water. Almonds and/or milk are used in some variants. Use your almond flavoured water instead of plain water when soaking the rice. This recipe might give you a starting point:

http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/gale-gand/horchata-recipe/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I used up a pot full of almond water because I refused to throw all that good stuff away. I first drank it cold from the fridge when I got thirsty :) It's an interesting mild flavor, but it might take some getting used to. I used some more to make an apple drink (crush apples in blender, slowly add this water to it until you get the desired consistency). I used up the last cups to make rice. In my opinion, that was the best use (although least exciting).

P.S.: The water tends to ferment over time. Doesn't taste terrible but it might not be the greatest idea to consume that.